# Restore deleted Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, restore, egit

I wanted to make a new git repository in eclipse and when I was deleting the old one, unluckily the whole project has been deletet from the workspace!

Is there any way to restore the project?

I would appreciate your answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have another repository with your work (like a central git server,another developer, another computer or something like that) you can just clone your repository back from that:

```
File -> Import -> Projects from Git -> URI ->
Type in your server/the other developers repo and complete the wizard.
```

---

And here is the reason why you lost your work:

In order to make git work, egit moves all the project files into the repository (which is only a special directory). Therefore, if you delete the repository, you also delete all the files in it, containing your whole project.

---

For the future:

To move your repository, just move it to another position using a normal file explorer. After that, tell eclipse about that by removing the repository from the repositories view (NOT deleting it):

```
In the Repositories View: Right-click on the repository ->
Remove from Repositories View
```

Then add the repository in its new location:

```
In the Repositories View: Upper right corner:
Add existing Git Repository to this view
```

Comment: Unluckily I don't have a another repository, but thank you for your description about how to prevent this next time, it is explained very well and now I think I am understanding it :D                                                                                         Thank you very much

Comment: Having another repository somewhere is always a good idea. As every repository contains a copy of the whole history, another repository acts as a fully-fledged backup. Just push every few days to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years late, but in case anyone else sees this: You can right click on the project folder and select "Restore From Local History...".
With any luck you should be able to restore the lost files from there.