# Deleting Git repository has deleted my project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

After migrating my Eclipse setup to a new PC and spending several days working on a project, I decided I better get the changes up on Git.

I created an empty Git repository at: `C:\Users\groob\git`

Couldn't see how to add my files to it, so I right-clicked the project and selected *Teams > Share...*
and created a Git repository at: `C:\Users\groob\git\listen`

At this point, I had two repositories, including one I didn't need, so I deleted `C:\Users\groob\git`

Now on restarting Eclipse, the project is gone, and more worryingly, the files are nowhere to be seen in the Explorer window.

Nothing in the Eclipse project:
[image]

Nothing in the Git directory:
[image]

Or the Workspace:
[image]

Even the trash is empty!

Where did they go and how can I get them back?

Comment: How exactly did you delete the Git repository (which commands did you execute in which paths)?

Comment: @dunni The first image above had two entries: User\groob\git and User\groob\git\listen. I right-clicked "User\groob\git" and selected the delete option. This obviously somehow contained the other repository: "User\groob\git\listen" and both disappeared.

Comment: Those are locations in your filesystem, and it looks like one is a parent of the other.

Comment: So creating a repository doesn't copy the files, it moves them?

Comment: No, the projects physically live under the location of the git repository instead of a location under the workspace. They're not moved, that's where they were created and are used.

Comment: What is shown as project _Location_ in _Project > Properties: Resource_?

Comment: @howlger Location: C:\Users\groob\git\listen\ListenB Updated: 30 December 2018 3:41:00 pm. The act of creating the egit repository seems to have rewritten this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So creating a repository doesn't copy the files, it moves them?

It does not copy or move files, your files were still in `Users\groob\git\listen`, subfolder of `Users\groob\git`.
Deleting the `Users\groob\git` folder will remove everything under it, Git repo or not.

Don't create an empty Git repo first, but [do share directly your existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25515427/6309).

Comment: Thanks VonC. I understand that deleting the parent also deleted everything in it, including the 2nd rep. I created. Why was the content of the workspace also deleted? I would expect this to be unaffected by the creation or deletion of a repository.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like I am screwed:
[Restore deleted Eclipse Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601987/restore-deleted-eclipse-project)

I was able to recover recent changes with "Restore From Local History...", and thankfully, I have a backup for the rest, but I still can't believe Git can trash everything so completely and so quickly.

Comment: To the moderators 
>>"This does not provide an answer to the question."
The linked answer "Restore deleted Eclipse Project" gives details to the answer that it cannot be recovered. Admittedly, "I am screwed" may not be the best way to say this, but it does have the correct meaning that it cannot be recovered. Perhaps you could reconsider whether this answers the original question or not?

Comment: again to the moderators, you might want to consider what value editors such as howlger, above, contribute to the site. Adding "C:\" to my paths may not actually be correct. Isn't it "C:\\" ? It could even be another drive letter. I think the original answer is sufficient in that it shows a path. Secondly "git" --> "Git". Really?

Answer (score 0):

In workspace there is a .metadata folder

There are files according to date modified which can be opened in notepad

and that code can be copied from there to project

I recovered it from there

C:\Users\akanksha\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history