# How to restore a deleted project on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, delete-file

I finally decided to create a new workspace for the first time today since the first one is starting to look a little too crowded for me. So, I create a new workspace and then transfer one project to the new area. 
I then deleted the project in the old workspace thinking that I don't need to have the project in two seperate workspaces. 
After that, I couldn't open it anymore. But I can still see the project folder from the new workspace. It's just that when I try to open it, it says that the project is missing.

NOTE: I remembered clicking the delete from disk button.

I can't find the folder on any of the workspaces. I can't "Restore From Local History." Clicking command+Z didn't help.

Comment: Sorry you cannot ): It is gone forever ):

Comment: Do you have a backup or revision control?

Comment: @aydinugur No...........;( There goes my work. Down the drain.

Comment: @FredLarson I've never thought about backing it up

Comment: I'll mark this as duplicate, it has been asked many times. @Siv, while you have not overwritten everything with other data, try using a data recovery software to see if you can recover anything. I have used Recuva in the past (which has a free and easy to use version) however I don't know if it still good or of any other suitable tools around. Best of luck to you. Sadly, all of us have been in your shoes at one time or another :/

Comment: @trymanI I'm using a mac though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse project was deleted how to undo it? or recover it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736733/eclipse-project-was-deleted-how-to-undo-it-or-recover-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restore deleted Eclipse Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601987/restore-deleted-eclipse-project)

Comment: @Siv Sorry, I have no info on how you could effectively proceed, especially on Mac that I haven't used at all. But I am aware of a feature "Time Machine" if it is available on your machine. In any case, you would be better off with a general search for "data recovery on Mac", "data recovery software Mac" or something similar. You could also check on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)